# Can you find what user is clicking a component or causing init?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Is there a way to find what user is clicking on a component. I have read that the $User variable is not available in Lightning. Is there a way to find out what user caused an init method to fire ?

Comment: You can check who the current user is on component load from a server side controller

Comment: And that says which user has that component open ? What if multiple users have it open ?

Comment: your controller will exectue each time a user loads the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add a server side controller to your component and use the [UserInfo Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) to obtain this information.